# Xcode won't import the appstore.mobileprovision-file

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, certificate, provisioning

I'm trying to get my first app on the app-store and have been following the instruction of my teacher (creating certificate, app-id and provisioning profile.) When I double click my mobile provisioning file, xcode opens but it just doesn't show up. 
When I click the provisioning profile-box in build settings it just shows me a blank space to type into (see screenshot)
[image: screenshot]

After trying to uninstall and reinstall xcode, redo the certificate, app ID and mobileprovision-file and trying to load the mobile provisioning file via window-devices(rightclick my mac) add provisioning profile (It doesn't work. The mobileprovision-file is grayed out) 
I don't know what to do. 
Even my teacher said he had no idea what the problem is or how to fix it.

I'm running xcode ver 7.1.1

Comment: can you upload the screenshot.

Comment: have you created distribution certificate by giving the keychain access.

Comment: I'm sorry if I misunderstand you. On my apple developer-page I can see the created profile for my app (with the correct id) under provisioning profiles > distribution. I have downloaded this file and double-clicked it but it does not show up in xcode. What is keychain access?

Comment: You need to give keychain access in your system and then create certificates .

Comment: Just Check this links what you want to do.   TEST APP ON DEVICE

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-test-your-app-on-an-ios-device--mobile-13861

SUBMIT APP IN APP STORE

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-submit-an-ios-app-to-the-app-store--mobile-16812

Comment: All of my certificates are on the login keychain and that's unlocked. I went in an manually allowed all keys to all programs and still no luck. The system keychain is empty. I can unlock it but it relocks as soon as I go somewhere else. Still same problem in xcode. What is it that I need to do?

Comment: Try setting Code Signing Identity > Release to your distribution certificate

Comment: When I press the code signing identity I get the same thing; a blank box where I can write, no dropdown menu to select anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editor -> Show values (the problem was not the keys but simply that I could not see them in xcode)